# jQuery widget (jPanelMenu) stops working on meteor route change

Tags: meteor, jpanelmenu

I have implemented jPanel Menu via a rendered template, which works great, until a route has been changed, then the menu stops working. Here is the code I am using to evoke the plugin.

```
  Template.mobileMenu.rendered = function(){
    var jPM = $.jPanelMenu({
        menu: '#mobile-menu',
        trigger: '.menu-trigger'
    });
    jPM.on();
  };
```

The template is loaded on all pages in the footer. I am thinking it needs to be rerun on route change, OR prevented from being rerun. I am not sure which. Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to wrap it in an if not rendered, to prevent it from being re-rendered on template / route changes.

```
Template.mobileMenu.rendered = function(){
  if (!this.rendered){

    var jPM = $.jPanelMenu({
        menu: '#mobile-menu',
        trigger: '.menu-trigger'
    });
    jPM.on();

    this.rendered = true;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to the problem many people have with using 3rd-party ui components.  I put together a working example of using a modal dialog component which may be of some help:

https://github.com/alanning/meteor-modal-example

Also I should point out that the new Meteor UI rendering system, "Blaze", should eliminate these kinds of issues.  I would expect Blaze to be released soon.

(For those visitors coming from the future, at the time of writing Meteor v0.7.0.1 is the latest version.)

Comment: I see you are loading the library for multiselect via the script tag on the template, does this help?

Comment: That is an optimization; on mobile phones (not tablets), the native multi-select elements are used rather than the custom loudev pretty one.  It shouldn't have an effect on getting your jPanel Menu to work unless there is some kind of a bug in the uglifyJS compressor that meteor uses that would cause jpanel to not work if minified/gzipped.

Comment: I have some more information, after first loading the jpanel menu loads correctly. But on a route change, the code is rerun and then loads a second menu, thus breaking the script.

Comment: Yes, I had exactly that problem.  Most widgets seem to not be able to gracefully handle being called multiple times on the same elements.  In the example, I figured out a way to trigger a 'safe' re-apply:  https://github.com/alanning/meteor-modal-example/blob/master/client/manage-roles.js#L45-L61
In your case, I'd recommend adding a check to see if it has already been loaded.  Some kind of a persistent flag, perhaps on the template itself.  EDIT - Oh, looks like that's just what you did.  Well done!